# noheader on the user/frontend side

Tags: redirect, forms, headers

I have an application which has the following structure on the user/frontend side:

```
usercontroller: generates output
userformhandler: processes user input and redirects back to usercontroller
```

So, when the user inputs data the following type of URL is called:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=4&ftype=userform&func=edit&noheader=true
```

In this model, the userformhandler processes the data, saves it and then redirects back to the usercontroller. On the admin side (which calls ftype=adminform) this works fine. On the user side however, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: CANNOT MODIFY HEADER INFORMATION - HEADERS ALREADY SENT BY 
(OUTPUT STARTED AT /VAR/WWW/HTML//WORDPRESS/WP-INCLUDES/L10N.PHP:156) 
IN /VAR/WWW/HTML/WORDPRESS/WP-INCLUDES/PLUGGABLE.PHP ON LINE 881
```

The headers are being sent from the search box of the twentyeleven theme. Some investigation leads me to believe that the noheader parameter is only honored in ./wp-admin/admin.php ...

Seeing this, is there any way to do this type of processing on the user side without generating headers, ie: do some processing which does not generate output and redirect back to another controller on the user side?

Greetings/Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be sending your header(s)/processing the request *before* the template loads.

In fact, a hook was added specifically for this: `template_redirect`

Comment: @user13955 Please don’t forget to mark this answer as _the answer_ (the checkmark on the left ✔).